# Wordpress Slow SQL Query for single page

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a job search box which searches in custom post type - `jobs` using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_posts AS posts INNER JOIN
     wp_postmeta AS postmeta
     ON postmeta.post_id = posts.ID
 WHERE post_type='job' AND post_status='publish' AND
       ((postmeta.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_posted_by' AND
         postmeta.meta_value IN (1640,2764,11487,11783,24831,24985,33113,39346,40194,41158,43157,44307,45447)
        ) OR
        (posts.post_title LIKE '%Con%')
       );
```

This query at times work very fast like within a second, but at times it gives result in 3 seconds.

Here is the EXPLAIN plan:

```
+------+-------------+----------+------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys            | key              | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+----------+------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | posts    | ref  | PRIMARY,type_status_date | type_status_date | 164     | const,const         | 2897 | Using index condition |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | postmeta | ref  | post_id,meta_key         | post_id          | 8       | afkmgfwugp.posts.ID | 20   | Using where           |
+------+-------------+----------+------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------+
```

How can I optimize this SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as a `union all`:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'job' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND
      p.post_title LIKE '%Con%'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.ID
FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN
     wp_postmeta pm
     ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'job' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND
      p.post_title NOT LIKE '%Con%' AND
      pm.meta_key = 'jobsearch_field_job_posted_by' AND
      pm.meta_value IN (1640, 2764, 11487, 11783, 24831, 24985, 33113, 39346, 40194, 41158, 43157, 44307, 45447);
```

I would recommend indexes on `wp_posts(post_type, post_status, post_title)`.  And on `wp_postmeta(meta_key, meta_value, post_id)`.